# Looper MessageQueue stops being processed after a while

Tags: android, message-queue, android-looper

I am working on an app that unfortunately has to mix the logical work with the UI a little bit.
Because of that, I am calling `runOnUiThread(...)` quite often.

That works fine until after a while, the posted `Runnables` just aren't processed any more.
The `Looper` dump starts to look like this:

> dump: Handler (android.os.Handler) {6765f9a}
>   dump: ..Looper (main, tid 2) {eff9c0}
>   dump: ....Message 0: { when=-4m25s628ms barrier=1015 }
>   dump: ....Message 1: { when=-4m25s399ms callb...
>   dump: ....Message 2: { when=-4m23s550ms callb...
>   dump: ....Message 3: { when=-4m15s696ms callb...
>   dump: ....Message 4: { when=-4m14s654ms callb...
>   dump: ....Message 5: { when=-4m13s561ms what=...
>   dump: ....Message 6: { when=-4m13s413ms callb...
>   dump: ....Message 7: { when=-4m12s339ms callb...
>   dump: ....Message 8: { when=-4m11s312ms what=...
>   dump: ....Message 9: { when=-4m11s307ms callb...
>   dump: ....Message 10: { when=-4m11s306ms what...
>   dump: ....Message 11: { when=-4m11s305ms what...
>   dump: ....Message 12: { when=-4m11s304ms what...
>   dump: ....Message 13: { when=-4m11s184ms call...
>   dump: ....Message 14: { when=-4m10s152ms call...
>   dump: ....Message 15: { when=-4m9s81ms what=1...
>   dump: ....Message 16: { when=-4m9s79ms callba...
>   dump: ....Message 17: { when=-4m9s79ms what=2...
>   dump: ....Message 18: { when=-4m3s846ms callb...
>   dump: ....Message 19: { when=-3m56s275ms call...
>   dump: ....Message 20: { when=-3m55s186ms what...
>   dump: ....Message 21: { when=-3m47s831ms call...
>   dump: ....Message 22: { when=-3m39s412ms call...
>   ... 
>   ...

and the `MessageQueue` gets longer every time I post something, and it's not just that I post new `Runnables` faster than they can be processed, they aren't processed **at all.**

Why is that?

(I'm kind of new to `Loopers` etc. so I'm wondering: Does the barrier have something to do with it? The timestamp of the messages after `Message 0` are always less than the barrier timestamp, but that's the way it's supposed to be, right?)

**Edit:**
I just realized this might be relevant: I sometimes get this `IllegalStateException: The specified message queue synchronization  barrier token has not been posted or has already been removed.` and don't know what that means, where it occurs or what to do about it.

Comment: I think it may have something to do with how you're dumping them. How _are_ you dumping them?

Comment: I am dumping them using ```Handler.dump((Printer) x -> Log(... + x))```... (I also edited the question, maybe you know something about the exception)

Comment: But more importantly, how are you calling `Handler.dump()`? What thread are you using?

Comment: I have a method ```update()``` which is sometimes called from the UI thread, sometimes from an ```AsyncTask```. In ```update()```, I create ```Handler h = new Handler(MainActivity.getInstance().getMainLooper());```. (I then check if the method has been invoked from the UI thread, if so I update some stuff, otherwise I call ```runOnUiThread()``` to do the update stuff) After that I call ```h.dump((Printer) x -> Log(..x..));```

I just wonder why it works for a while and then sometimes (not always) this problem emerges...

Comment: I believe I understand; just one more question: How often is `update()` running? That is, can you guarantee that the UI thread has sufficient free cycles to start dispatching queued items?

Comment: I am using ```runOnUiThread()``` at most 4 times a second, and only sometimes, most of the time it's called 0.5 to 2 times per second. I thinkt that should be plenty of cycles for the ```Looper```. Do you know anything about that exception?

Comment: That may be related. You can see some documentation [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/MessageQueue.java#448). Maybe you have a library which is using an unsupported internal API.

Comment: I do not use any external libraries. I also tried my best not to mix ```support``` and ```androix```.

Comment: In that case, I'm probably gonna need to see an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).